# How to merge multiple generic TypeScript lists into a new list with a union type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a TypeScript method that merges an arbitrary number of generic lists into a new list, where the new list's type is a union of the types of the items in the original lists.

I have a List class as follows:

```
class List<T> {
    private items: T[];

    constructor() {
        this.items = [];
    }

    push(item: T): void {
        this.items.push(item);
    }

    getItems(): T[] {
        return this.items;
    }
}
```

I want to add a static merge method to List that takes an arbitrary number of List objects and merges their items into a new List object:

```
class List<T> {
    // ...existing code...

    static merge(...lists: List<any>[]): List<any> {
        // TODO: implementation
    }
}
```

The merge method should handle List objects of any type and return a new List object where the type of the items is a union of the types of the items in the input lists.

For example:

```
const stringList = new List<string>();
const numberList = new List<number>();

const mergedList = List.merge(stringList, numberList);
```

After this code, mergedList should be a `List<string | number>`.

How can I implement the merge method to achieve this?

The challenge is that TypeScript's type inference is not able to automatically infer the correct union type for the items in the merged list, and it defaults to any. I want a type-safe solution that doesn't rely on the any type.

I tried to do something like this but I get a `List<any>`

```
static merge<T extends any[]>(...lists: { getItems: () => any }[]): List<T[number]> {
        const mergedList = new List<T[number]>();
        
        lists.forEach(list => {
            list.getItems().forEach(item => mergedList.push(item));
        });
        
        return mergedList;
    }
```

Comment: Nowhere do you actually say that `lists` is a list of `List<...>`. You can amend that by mapping over the generic parameter `T` to `List<T[K]>`: https://tsplay.dev/mM726w

Comment:  Hmm I posted a comment with something similar earlier, asking for 1) an edit to fix the fact that `T` isn't mentioned in the `merge` parameters, and 2) if [this](https://tsplay.dev/WP8AkW) solution worked for them. Either it was a mod (do we get notified for such things?) or some SO glitch.  Anyway I concur with the above and I'd be happy to write up an answer if it works and I'm not missing something.

Comment: Yeah I think that's what I  was missing.

Comment: So @zenly do you want to write this up? If not, I'll do it.

Comment: @jcalz Nah don't got the time, you can go ahead.

Comment: Okay I’ll do so when I get back to a real computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem with the call signature

```
{
   merge<T extends any[]>(...lists: { getItems: () => any }[]): List<T[number]>;
}
```

is that the `lists` parameter has no dependence whatsoever on the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `T`.  That means `T` will completely fail to be inferred, fall back to the [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `any`, and therefore the return type will tend to be `List<any>`.

---

The obvious fix is to return `T` and not `any` from the `getItems()` method in your type, like this:

```
static merge<T extends any[]>(
    ...lists: { getItems: () => T }[]
): List<T[number]> {
    const mergedList = new List<T[number]>();
    lists.forEach(list => {
        list.getItems().forEach(item => mergedList.push(item));
    });
    return mergedList;
}
```

This will work with a *homogeneous* array of arguments:

```
const okayMergedList = List.merge(stringList, stringList, stringList);
// const okayMergedList: List<string>
```

but unfortunately errors if you pass a *heterogeneous* collection of input lists:

```
const mergedList = List.merge(stringList, numberList); // error!    
// -------------------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~
//     Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.

// (method) List<T>.merge<string[]>(
//   ...lists: { getItems: () => string[]; }[]
// ): List<string>
```

Since `stringList.getItems()` returns `string[]`, one candidate for `T` is `string[]`, while since `numberList.getItems()` returns `number[]`, another candidate for `T` could be `number[]`.  But given those two candidates, the compiler just picks the first one, causing `numberList` to be in error.  It would have worked if the compiler synthesized the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `string[] | number[]` from the different candidates, but the compiler does not do that.  Often that's a *good* thing, since usually people don't want something like `function compare<T>(x: T, y: T): boolean` to allow `compare(123, "abc")`.  But here it causes an unfortunate error.  And there is no way to ask the compiler to synthesize such a union; see [microsoft/TypeScript#44312](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44312) for a relevant feature request.

---

So we need to refactor further. Here I'd say that instead of `T` being the return type of `getItems()`, we should allow `T` to be the [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of element types of `getItems()` return types, with one element of `T` for each argument to `mergedList()`. So for `List.merge(stringList, numberList)`, I want `T` to be inferred as `[string, number]`.  (There are two levels of array in this call signature; `lists` is of an outer array type, containing elements whose `getItems()` method returns an inner array type.  I am changing `T` to correspond to the *outer* array type and not the *inner* array type.)

Like this:

```
static merge<T extends any[]>(
    ...lists: { [I in keyof T]: { getItems: () => T[I][] } }
): List<T[number]> {
    const mergedList = new List<T[number]>();
     lists.forEach(list => {
        list.getItems().forEach(item => mergedList.push(item));
    });
    return mergedList;
}
```

Here the type of `lists` is a [mapped tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) over `T`. For each numericlike index `I` of `T`, the element of `T` at that index, `T[I]`, is mapped to `{ getItems: () => T[I][] }`.  So if the `0`th element of `T` is `string`, then the `0`th element of `args` is `{ getItems: () => string[] }`.

Let's test it out:

```
const mergedList = List.merge(stringList, numberList);
// const mergedList: List<string | number>;

// (method) List<T>.merge<[string, number]>(
//   lists_0: { getItems: () => string[]; }, 
//   lists_1: { getItems: () => number[]; }
// ): List<string | number>
```

Looks good! `T` is inferred as `[string, number]` from the arguments, and the output is `List<string | number>` as desired!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOZIN4ChD8kSl4AbEKKJAGQygBcAeAFQD49jSeZMA3EI2QZhYKAC4krANoBdANyEePeAHtgTNAFd4jNWgAUASjxJGACwYA6URHFIAvEnkKkAX2UqSMbVAuGdmBSrMZS-GoYACZmljZBUNa+-oFixm6e3N5YEIwAkmJQJiHyZmi52mjA5laJCRlE3iRMQhjwSJBoOWxIEAAewsBRNCDAAJ7y7IZZTSTW8+QMjJJmOfmFUiZOnKNjHvIzPGF0S2wywNpgAEYQaHKcBLOqGkwdtzlR9K-OwBAA7icmGcLtdbvcTEpDk1FkxEgAzAwAUQQARhjG2XCe0KW1jWBXsRWM1gRaGR8ACQQxnQ+X0YST8FLS6Sh3nczJZKnKjEq1WpEE+SyUs08PEyz006K0GGAWFpTiQvwBtOYUplU2Z4teIJuaDlP3+gJY2tu6shmvRfIF30N1j5hlVsqWABoFZcdbT2ZlQJBYAhkAAFEBoRgYEDkABiGD6mNIFCoNGVHBj3j4GEEwiQCRKii83nUEp0egMW1wNXihXlrg8uZUyUZ9hCxwi0VitVshXpKSC6WrHLxhWK0lKpa5PLLdUKDQ5LRD7T5PX6g2GSF2k2mWLmCyWK1L-YJm1Mjk4rH2cg5x0T5zdYIeHPNby6-L1CoNl+Nd1Nd9IaPhSJRhjRDFHg3Hg0VxXJ8XEExiT-clUnsKl3ifHE63gsBjA1Dc2SFDdRyqB8aUFDkRVIMVYxeSVGEwGVn0VQ0VSo6UsE-e931o19TnfT8ZnzV41AAaxAMYAFkkKtdFnFpW0kPtRiaOdJAHVpF0lKWTCSAAeg0sgKKQAShNEx9xKkZUHXYGteItMTnyku1VKYF02LUtwtN6NA0AMABCHgZlcgBaALAqC4KQtCsK-M4AA-aKYti3ztJ4VgxhgZAAHJ33kVLMxoYA1HReNsFAK5yGQfRzGStKHUy6wa1cwxIEsNQolMRN2Gkx8GOorA13i0h5msH8pF3CCNiQLYj0UuTusUU9eovU4zMITxvWgOBECQSNowIHjKGoeik2AlMBCEERRtkHMOUswt9CMUxSziCcCUrGayJTBk0MbcJIhie62wSTt63QqdZj3KDjnOsoKnwh72wJKdp0YVo5yQhcBggIYRnGHqQP6wazBkPJM2qfiIDGNQ4WkOQhqQUGVnG48CbkUp3GrWZ5qBWR33uZMnksgjkOtOi32vD8IRrWYfxg0l-0AibDpApAwNp6CSTJQHEKMqTUO7dSnmw8Wmjw3lrKI4UZlenSJUmrr2KVBappY8iracwWOKBLixZ43TLRsnE7Km5TXVBXVnN6vmfaWEz7a6pAAB8g51dgcJIXr6tyCwmpa04OHa7oZAdRyRfBXqSB-AB9AAGanaYPDEqpel0S8V7cy4ARmrkb9zGw9OAyl65qjoEHTjhOTXwdwgA)